# Unread count for Public Dialog in Quickblox

Tags: flutter, quickblox

In our application, we are having users join a bunch of public dialogs when they log in to the app for the first time.
From the next time they open the app, we would like to show the unread count but the SDK is always returning the unread count as 0.
Does Quickblox support the unread message count parameter for public dialogs as they do for group dialogs?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get count of unread messages in public dialogs, turned out it is expected.

Works only for group/private dialogs.